# Access every character in a list of strings avoiding nested for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy

I'm currently working with some DNA sequence data, and I need to create a matrix of frequencies for each site. For example, something like this:

```
A   T   G   C
0.2 0.3 0.3 0.2
0.3 0.4 0.1 0.2
0.7 0.1 0.1 0.1
```

The input is a list of many DNA sequences, for example:

```
te_seqs = ["ATCTACTGATG", "ATACAGTACATAGA", "ATAGACAGTTGTGCG", "GTCGATACGT", ...]
```

Each sequence is thousands of characters long and there are thousands of sequences. The output is a numpy matrix that contains the frequency counts for each site. For example, in the data above, the first site has 3 As and 1 G, so the frequency of A is 3/4 = 0.75 and the frequency of G is 1/4 = 0.25. The frequencies of T and C are both 0.

I currently have a list of all my sequences, and I'm getting frequencies by adding 1 to an Nx4 matrix. The problem is I'm working with a lot of sequences and nested for loops is not ideal time wise:

```
for seq in te_seqs:
    for i,nuc in enumerate(seq):
        if nuc == "A":
            te_pwm[i, 0] = te_pwm[i, 0] + 1 
        elif nuc == "T":
            te_pwm[i, 1] = te_pwm[i, 1] + 1
        elif nuc == "G":
            te_pwm[i, 2] = te_pwm[i, 2] + 1
        elif nuc == "C":
            te_pwm[i, 3] = te_pwm[i, 3] + 1

for seq in gene_seqs:
    for i,nuc in enumerate(seq):
        if nuc == "A":
            gene_pwm[i, 0] = gene_pwm[i, 0] + 1 
        elif nuc == "T":
            gene_pwm[i, 1] = gene_pwm[i, 1] + 1
        elif nuc == "G":
            gene_pwm[i, 2] = gene_pwm[i, 2] + 1
        elif nuc == "C":
            gene_pwm[i, 3] = gene_pwm[i, 3] + 1
```

My questions are 1) is there a more pythonic way of examining each string in a list of stings? 2) is there a better way to create a matrix of base frequencies?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please give some test data?

Comment: Yes, I am using data from here: http://maizetedb.org/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/maize/TE_search.cgi. Click on class II and download that data. There is more information here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/arundurvasula/9338256 but this write up is unfinished

Comment: Can you please explain your program with sample input and output? Its unclear as it is now.

Comment: I added some more explanation. The side of the matrix is each position in the sequence (site). Does that make sense? I can edit more as needed.

Comment: Thanks :) But still, what is `site`? That is an important piece of information, I believe.

Comment: site is the index in the sequence. site 1 is index 0.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes @JayanthKoushik is correct. A site is just a specific position in the DNA sequence. Site 1 in sequence 1 is `te_seqs[0][0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to iterate over the sites, and then use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do the counting:

```
import collections
import itertools

te_seqs = ["ATCTACTGATG", "ATACAGTACATAGA", "ATAGACAGTTGTGCG", "GTCGATACGT"]

sites = map(collections.Counter, itertools.izip_longest(*te_seqs))
for site in sites:
  A = site.get("A", 0)
  T = site.get("T", 0)
  G = site.get("G", 0)
  C = site.get("C", 0)
  total = float(A + T + G + C)
  print A / total, T / total, G / total, C / total
```

This produces

```
0.75 0.0 0.25 0.0
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
0.5 0.0 0.0 0.5
0.0 0.25 0.5 0.25
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.25 0.25 0.5
0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I modified the solution a little bit to fit in with adding the frequencies to a numpy array, but this worked great. Thanks again!